# Mac OS X 10.4 (Tiger) will not boot

Tags: macos, boot, osx-tiger

My G5 Tower all of a sudden started booting to the Registration page (a page that appears after installing Mac OS X, where you are supposed to register).

Since I can't get it to boot in safe mode, I used a USB 2.0 - SATA cable to connect my drive to my MacBook Pro. After that, using (CCC) Disc to Disc Clone, I copied all my data to an external Western Digital passport drive and made a startup disc.

My question is this: was there an easier and less time consuming solution than that? Does anyone know why this would happen all of a sudden?

Answer (score 1):

From what you describe .. for some reason your initial Apple  registration file was missing or corrupt.. That file is typically located in

```
/private/var/db/.AppleSetupDone
```

Hard to tell how it really happened....but I'd say you are on the right track using cloning software to get out of these situations. [Super Duper](http://www.shirt-pocket.com/SuperDuper/SuperDuperDescription.html) is another option.

If have or can acquire an external USB or Firewire drive for the tower, you could make it bootable and have a known good disc image  of the G5 on it to restore from...

Comment: Thank You for your help, I cloned the drive and then I did run the set up. It gave me a new user as described by the Spif says below. When I logged on to the new user it would not allow me to see the old users unless I went into the directly in to the directory. I was then able to open the permissions allow rights and copy all the old files: Apps, Doc's, downloads, etc......It is all working good right now. Thank You both for the help!!!! If I can help you guys in any way just ask

Comment: Glad to help. Sorry about the Yanks opening nite 2010 ( sox fan here ) .. You can upvote answers that are helpful , and click the checkmark for answers you consider your accepted answer..

Answer (score 1):

Rerunning the setup assistant wouldn't have hurt anything. You would've ended up with a second set of network settings and a second local admin user, both of which you could have gone in and deleted a minute later.

Answer (score 0):

You can skip the optional parts of the setup assistant by pressing ⌘Q. I don't know whether it would still insist on creating an account if you already have one.